# How to get deduped conversions per unique users with a 24 hour window

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get deduped conversions for each unique user. The rule here is that I need a column where I only get the count of the first conversion made within a day. So I can trigger 10 conversions for 3/28/2019, but the 'Deduped' column will only pull in the count for 1.

This is my original data in BigQuery:

```
Date    User_ID
3/3/19  1234
3/3/19  1234
3/3/19  1234
3/3/19  12
3/3/19  12
3/4/19  1234
3/4/19  1234
3/5/19  1
```

I want my final output to look like this:

```
Date     User_ID   Total_Conversions   Deduped
3/3/19   1234      3                   1
3/3/19   12        2                   1
3/5/19   1         1                   1
3/4/19   1234      2                   1
```

Comment: something not clear with your question - the way you "defined" it - looks like `deduped` will always be `1` . Am I missing something. Please clarify

Comment: This is right! Apologies if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT day, user_id, 
  COUNT(1) total_conversions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) deduped
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY day, user_id
```

If apply above to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row day     user_id total_conversions   deduped  
1   3/4/19  1234    2                   1    
2   3/5/19  1       1                   1    
3   3/3/19  1234    3                   1    
4   3/3/19  12      2                   1
```

Note: check my comments I left below your question!

> How about if we didn't have the date column in the final output, what if the deduped rule was constructed within the code to where the grouping would be based on the uder_id without the 'day' column in the final output?

Below example does this

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '3/3/19' day, 1234 user_id UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/3/19', 1234 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/3/19', 1234 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/3/19', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/3/19', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/4/19', 1234 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/4/19', 1234 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/5/19', 1 
)
SELECT user_id, 
  COUNT(1) total_conversions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT day) deduped
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY user_id
```

with result

```
Row user_id total_conversions   deduped  
1   12      2                   1    
2   1       1                   1    
3   1234    5                   2
```

Comment: Perfect! How about if we didn't have the date column in the final output, what if the deduped rule was constructed within the code to where the grouping would be based on the uder_id without the 'day' column in the final output?

Comment: show expected output based on input presented in your question

Comment: So this is the second problem i'm trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410752/getting-deduped-conversions-per-unique-users-with-a-24-hour-window

Comment: please accept and vote up the answer if it helped, so I will get to your next question :o)