# Getting deduped conversions per unique users with a 24 hour window

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get deduped conversions for each unique user. The rule here is that I need a column where I only get the count of the first conversion made within a day. So I can trigger 10 conversions for 3/03/2019, but the 'Deduped' column will only pull in the count for 1. The code should be scalable for TB of data.

This is my original data in BigQuery:

```
Date    User_ID Total_Conversions
3/3/19  1234    1
3/3/19  1234    1
3/3/19  1234    1
3/3/19  12      1
3/3/19  12      1
3/4/19  1234    1
3/4/19  1234    1
3/5/19  1       1
3/6/19  1       0
```

I want my final output to look like this:

```
Date     User_ID   Total_Conversions   Deduped
3/3/19   1234          3                   1
3/3/19   12            2                   1
3/5/19   1             1                   1
3/4/19   1234          2                   1
3/6/19   1             0                   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a basic `GROUP BY` query here:

```
SELECT
    date,
    User_ID,
    SUM(Total_Conversions) AS Total_Conversions,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Total_Conversions) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Deduped
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    date,
    User_ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

(Demo shown in MySQL just for illustrative purposes)

This assumes that logically the `Deduped` column is always one, for any number of conversions in that group, unless no conversions at all happened, in which it becomes zero.

Comment: i love. you're amazing! Such an easy solve, i knew the case statement would help solve this.

Comment: Thanks! I sometimes forget stackoverflow etiquette :P